# T-SQL Where clause with nvarchar composed by a string_agg in openquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, openquery

I'm creating a stored procedure where I have this openquery:

```
SELECT @MY_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(HYPER_CONN, ''
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(QUANT_RIGA),0) FROM DDT_CLI_RIGHE WHERE DOC_RIGA_ID = ''''' + @THE_DDT + ''''' '')'
```

In the where clause I set this variable `@THEDDT`:

```
DECLARE @THE_DDT nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT STRING_AGG(DOC_RIGA_ID,',') FROM ...
```

For example it will be like `@THEDDT = test1,test2,test3`

I want set this variable in my "where in" clause.

So in the openquery I'm trying to have something like this (but using the varaible):

```
WHERE DOC_RIGA_ID IN ('test1','test2','test3')
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "without creating tables"? You don't create any tables in the above. You just have 2 variable assignments; the first with a literal and the latter from a data set.

Comment: Please add your SP code by all of them query for clear what you need . and don't use `Select *` in stored procedure so use `Select col1,col2 ... `

Comment: @Amirhossein the select * is on openquery, but inside i have select col1. The SP is enough long, i think that no sense add everything. I try to explain better.

Comment: Think about it... you need to just change your `DOC_RIGA_ID = {literal}` clause to a `DOC_RIGA_ID IN ({delimited List})` clause...

Comment: but this way not working because @THE_DDT is a string, so if u do a where in, it will take the entire string, not splitted. I hope to explained the problem

Comment: The "where in " is part of the text in the `@MY_QUERY`. Only after the string is ready with the "where in" as part of the text in `@MY_QUERY`, then you execute it as a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a stab in the dark, as we don't have all the information, however, as I mentioned, it *seems* all you need to do is change your `DOC_RIGA_ID = {literal}` clause to a `DOC_RIGA_ID IN ({delimited List})` clause:

```sql
DECLARE @THE_DDT nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(DOC_RIGA_ID,''''),',') --Assumes DOC_RIGA_ID can't have a value longer than 128 characters
                                  FROM ...

SELECT @MY_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(HYPER_CONN, ''
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(QUANT_RIGA),0) FROM DDT_CLI_RIGHE WHERE DOC_RIGA_ID IN (' + REPLACE(@THE_DDT,'''','''''') + ')'') OQ;';
```

This is, of course, untested as I have no way of testing this statement.